# C# XmlNode has ancestor type

Tags: c#, xmldocument, xmlnode, ancestor

I have an XmlDocument in the format below. If I perform the following search

```
XmlNode title = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Book/Title[contains(., \"Title3\")]");
```

I will get back an XmlNode which is a title. How do I find out if that book falls under publications? I don't always want to assume that title.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode exists. There should be an intuitive way to say:

```
if(title.hasAncestor("Publication") != null)
{
    // do whatever
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
<Publications>
    <Novel>
        <Book>
            <Title>Title1</Title>
            <Author>Author1</Author>
            <Year>2000</Year>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Title>Title2</Title>
            <Author>Author2</Author>
            <Year>2000</Year>
        </Book>
    </Novel>
    <History>
        <Book>
            <Title>Title3</Title>
            <Author>Author3</Author>
            <Year>2000</Year>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Title>Title4</Title>
            <Author>Author4</Author>
            <Year>2000</Year>
        </Book>
    </History>
</Publications>
<StudyGuides>
    <Math>
        <Book>
            <Title>Title5</Title>
            <Author>Author5</Author>
            <Year>2000</Year>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Title>Title6</Title>
            <Author>Author6</Author>
            <Year>2000</Year>
        </Book>
    </Math>
    <Science>
        <Book>
            <Title>Title7</Title>
            <Author>Author7</Author>
            <Year>2000</Year>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Title>Title8</Title>
            <Author>Author8</Author>
            <Year>2000</Year>
        </Book>
    </Science>
</StudyGuides>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in XPath by using the `ancestor` axis:

```
//Book/Title[contains(., "Title3")][ancestor::Publications]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I get that will get me all title nodes with the innerText of "Title3" under Publications. but what if I have an XmlNode and what to determine after that if it's under publications or a StudyGuides?

Perhaps I'm looking at it wrong? Possibly I need to see if the node falls is a child node under "Publications" in the XmlDocument?

Comment: @Koenyn If you have the `Title` node as an `XmlNode` then either use `XmlNode.ParentNode` recursively or `titleNode.SelectSingleNode(".[ancestor::Publications]") == null`.

Comment: :) thanks. Really appreciate it. I had to change it to titleNode.SelectSingleNode("ancestor::Publications") == null

Answer (score 0):

```
/Publications/*/Book/Title[contains(., 'Title3')]
```